# Swift-Binary operator cannot be applied to operands, when converting degrees to radians

Tags: swift, xcode, variables, random, angle

I'm aware of some relatively similar questions on this site, but if they do apply to my problem (which I'm not certain they do) then I certainly don't understand them. Here's my problem;

```
var degrees = UInt32()
var radians = Double()

let degrees:UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(360)
let radians = angle * (M_PI / 180)
```

This returns an error, focused on the multiplication star, reading; "Binary operator "*" cannot be applied to operands of type 'UInt32' and 'Double'.

I'm fairly sure I need to have the degrees variable be of type UInt32 to randomise it, and also that the pi constant cannot be made to be of UInt32, or at least I don't know how, as I'm relatively new to Xcode and Swift in general.

I'd be very grateful if anyone had a solution to my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let degree = arc4random_uniform(360)

let radian = Double(degree) * .pi/180
```

you need to convert the degree to double before the multiplication .

from apple swift book:

**Integer and Floating-Point Conversion**

Conversions between integer and floating-point numeric types must be made explicit:

```
let three = 3
let pointOneFourOneFiveNine = 0.14159
let pi = Double(three) + pointOneFourOneFiveNine
```

// pi equals 3.14159, and is inferred to be of type Double

Here, the value of the constant three is used to create a new value of type Double, so that both sides of
the addition are of the same type. Without this conversion in place, the addition would not be allowed.
Floating-point to integer conversion must also be made explicit. An integer type can be initialized
with a Double or Float value:

```
1 let integerPi = Int(pi)
2 // integerPi equals 3, and is inferred to be of type Int
```

Floating-point values are always truncated when used to initialize a new integer value in this way.
This means that 4.75 becomes 4, and -3.9 becomes -3.